# Generar círculos cada cierto tiempo

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

estoy intentando hacer un juego y quiero generar círculos cada 2 segundos pero estoy trabado. No se como hacerlo. Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias.

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView {

Paint paint;
int CantidadDeCirculos = 5;
int radio, alto, ancho;

public Juego(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i=0; i<CantidadDeCirculos; i++) {
        Random r = new Random();
        alto = r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
        ancho = r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
        radio = r.nextInt(101 - 50) + 50;
        canvas.drawCircle(ancho, alto, radio, paint);
    }
}
}
```

Tengo 5 círculos que se dibujan al iniciar la aplicación pero quisiera que se genere 1 circulo cada 2 segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello necesitas un Hilo (Thread), este sería un ejemplo.

```
public class Temporizador implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() 
{
    int esperar_segundos = 2;
    while(true)
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(esperar_segundos * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Esto se ejecuta cada " + esperar_segundos + " segundos");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Temporizador().run();
}

}
```

Solo tienes que reemplazar el

```
System.out.println("Esto se ejecuta cada " + esperar_segundos + " segundos");
```

Por lo que quieres que haga.